# group by does not work correctly join two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join, group-by

I want to get the number of tickets sold per payment method for each event. and i've the follow query:

```
SELECT  count(distinct(a.performance_id)) as EventQuantity,
        sum(a.admission_count)  as TicketQuantity
FROM   vw_PrecioTipoZona_Paid as a 
WHERE 1 = 1
AND a.performance_id ='DED63133-A099-4949-AA57-13BBE9462BAF'
GROUP BY a.performance_id
```

and I get this result, which is OK:

```
EventQuantity   TicketQuantity
   1                    203
```

But when join the table with other, the result wich is sum, in this case `a.admission_count` is multiplied by the number of records in the other table.

The query who has problem is this:

```
SELECT      a.performance_id,
            count(distinct(a.performance_id)) as EventQuantity,
            sum(a.admission_count)  as TicketQuantity,
            b.payment_method as PaymentMethod
FROM   vw_PrecioTipoZona_Paid as a inner join vw_Payment_UserByPerformance as b
       on a.performance_id = b.performance_id
WHERE 
    1 = 1
    and a.performance_id ='DED63133-A099-4949-AA57-13BBE9462BAF'
    group by a.performance_id, b.payment_method
```

With this query i'm getting this result:

```
EventQuantity   TicketQuantity  PaymentMethod
   1               10353            Cash
   1               5887             Card
   1               1624         MasterCardECommerce
   1                812           VisaEcommece
```

And this result is wron, the result should be:

```
EventQuantity   TicketQuantity  PaymentMethod
       1             111             Cash
       1              63             Card
       1              17       MasterCardECommerce
       1              8             VisaEcommece
```

The **vw_Payment_UserByPerformance** view structure is the follow:

```
performance_id  user_role_id    userrole_name   userrole_group  date_transaction    user_id user_name   owner_user_id   owner_user_name amount_adm_net  amount_req_net  amount_charge_charge    amount_total    amount_net  chargeTransaction   tax payment_method
```

And the **vw_PrecioTipoZona_Paid** view structure is the follow:

```
performance_id  performance_name    performance_start_date  date_transaction    user_role_id    userrole_name   userrole_group  user_id user_name   price_type  price_zone  price_zone_priority admission_count NET charge1 charge2 charge3 charge4 charge5 GROSS
```

Do I have to make subquery? Where is the problem here?

Comment: What is the expected result set? Also, what's the point in `count(distinct(a.performance_id))` since you are grouping by the same field?

Comment: Would be helpful to translate all identifies (table and column names in this case) to English, so we get a better understanding of the semantics of your table.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos 
I also want to know the number of tickets sold per type of payment for each event.

Comment: I would guess your `join` condition is wrong, there has to be a 1:1 relationship between the two tables for that to work (you might have to add the table descriptions if you want us to help you to indentify potential relations, although you should add them anyway to make your data model clearer). You also need to add `PaymentMethod` to your `group by`, which you probably already did, otherwise your 2nd query will not give the output you showed.

Comment: @Solarflare i thing this problem is because there are two view's, not tables.

Comment: Best way to debug is to to take out your aggregations and see what data is being multiplied due to your join.

Comment: No, you have to have 1 row in your table/view a that belong to 1 row in your table/view b. If several rows in table b belong to table a (e.g. if you can pay the full price by splitting it, e.g. pay part of it cash and the rest by mastercard), you have to sum a column in table b. But it is much easier to see what you have to do if you would show the columns of your tables/views a and b and maybe some example values.

Comment: Done @Solarflare, look the view's strucure now.

Comment: Some description and example data would help (e.g. the rows for 1 ticket (or one purchase, since there can be probably more tickets per purchase) in both tables/views), but if I have to guess, I would assume you have to add `and a.user_id = b.user_id` to your `on`-condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQl allows you to incorrectly use group by. You should never use the technique you used in this query.

```
SELECT      a.performance_id,
            count(distinct(a.performance_id)) as EventQuantity,
            sum(a.admission_count)  as TicketQuantity,
            b.payment_method as PaymentMethod
FROM   vw_PrecioTipoZona_Paid as a inner join vw_Payment_UserByPerformance as b
       on a.performance_id = b.performance_id
WHERE 
    a.performance_id ='DED63133-A099-4949-AA57-13BBE9462BAF'
    group by a.performance_id, b.payment_method
```

**When you use group by the only way to guarantee correct results is to group by all the non-aggregated fields.** All other databases make this part of the syntax and thus do not have this problem.

If this still does not give the correct results, then there is a problem with the specifics of what you intended vice what you wrote. We would need to see the business requirement, that table structure, the sample data in the tables and teh sample results in order to help you find the correct query.

Looking at your additional details added while I was writing this, I think you need to use a derived table.

```
SELECT      a.performance_id,
            count(a.performance_id) as EventQuantity,
            a.admission_count  as TicketQuantity,
            b.payment_method as PaymentMethod
FROM   (select performance_id, sum(admission_count) as Admissioncount vw_PrecioTipoZona_Paid 
WHERE a.performance_id ='DED63133-A099-4949-AA57-13BBE9462BAF'
group by performance_id )as a
 inner join vw_Payment_UserByPerformance as b
       on a.performance_id = b.performance_id
    group by a.performance_id, b.payment_method
```

Comment: This query return the same result that i have.

Answer (score 0):

You have it in your question already:

> I want to get the number of tickets sold per payment method and i've
>   the follow query

So you're basically looking at a query like this:

```
SELECT payment_method, COUNT(*) FROM x GROUP BY payment_method;
```

You seem to be doing something differently, the results could like like so if your group on the `payment_method` column as well:

```
SELECT      
    a.performance_id AS performanceId,
    b.payment_method AS paymentMethod,
    COUNT(*) numPayments
FROM   
    vw_PrecioTipoZona_Paid as a
INNER JOIN
    vw_Payment_UserByPerformance AS b ON (a.performance_id = b.performance_id)
WHERE 
    a.performance_id ='DED63133-A099-4949-AA57-13BBE9462BAF'
GROUP BY
    a.performance_id,
    b.payment_method
```

Comment: Not really @pintxo, i does not work for me. I want the quantity of tickets sales per payment method, it should be something like: Mastercard   3, Visa 1

Answer (score 0):

First, that doesn't make sense together:

```
SELECT a.performance_id,
       count(distinct(a.performance_id)) as EventQuantity,
...
GROUP BY a.performance_id
```

You're grouping the stuff having **the same** performance_id, and then you're asking to show you how many **DISTINCT** performance_ids are in the group.

Guess what the answer always be?

Second, SQL is a **declarative** language, so declare what you want first.

If you can't express it in SQL adequately (which is ok) - then do it in words, and please update your question with it.
Guessing on the lack of inputs is rarely productive.